# Map/reduce with index in Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary, reduce

How would one go about accomplishing something like the following in a more elegant way in Swift 4 e.g using map and/or reduce.

I've simplified the code for the sake of posting here, but note it does require the use of an index.

```
var numbers = [50, 20, 70, 80, 90]
var result = [0,0,0]
for number in numbers {
  for i in 0...2 {
    result[i] += number + i
  } 
}
```

The end result should be:

```
[Int] = 3 values {
  [0] = 310
  [1] = 315
  [2] = 320
}
```

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? Giving an example is helpful in most situations, but only giving an example can prove to be counteractive. Especially when you are asking for a better solution to a specific problem, since in this case you'll probably end up with a suboptimal solution to the real problem and an optimal/elegant one suiting the specific example. Btw there's no `Dictionary` in your code, so you either used the tag for no reason or your code doesn't produce the expected results.

Comment: `let sum = numbers.reduce(0, +); 
let result = (0...2).map({ $0 + sum })` but like Dávid said, that probably doesn't solve your real problem.

Comment: Side note, `numbers` doesn't seem to have any reason to be a variable.

Comment: Josh, That's not right. That yields `[310, 311, 312]`, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: What is the point of this? You're putting the sum of the elements of numbers into result, plus index*numbers.count. Why?

Comment: @DuncanC The code is actually slightly different and touches on some structs that were not included. I tried to simplify this enough to make it easier to answer.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I understand your point. The actual code is a bit more complex. I'll however try not to simplify this much for future questions. I'm marking Tomasz's response below as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is equivalent

```
let result = (0...2).map({ index in numbers.reduce(0) { (sum, current) in sum + current + index } })
```

or this if you want to use `result` array

```
let r = result.enumerated().map({ (index, _) in numbers.reduce(0) { (sum, current) in sum + current + index } })
```

but more efficient will be something like that

```
let sum = numbers.reduce(0, +)
let resultsExpected = 3
let result = (0..<resultsExpected).map({ $0 * numbers.count + sum })
```

Comment: Might be preferable to hoist the sum of `numbers` out of the loop.

Comment: Your second option is both clearer **and** more efficient. I was about to post your 2nd solution when I realized you already provided it. (Voted)

Comment: Agree with @DuncanC, I prefer the 2nd option as well. Thanks guys!